# How do I create a code snippet that appears on the current line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, code-snippets

I'm trying to create an HTML code snippet for vs 2010. The snippet so far is:

```
<Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<%= this.Resource("$resourceKey$") %>]]></Code>
```

However when I test this from a view page, the snippet appears on the next line. For example:

```
<h1>
<%= this.Resource("Blah") %><h1>
```

I want it to appear on the current line. Can't find any solutions online so can anyone help?